# Nested ranged for loops for iterating through vectors

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops, stdvector, nested-for-loop

Consider the following code snippet, taken for a program that works fine.

As you can see, It uses 2 nested `for` loops to iterate through a `vector` of `vector`s:

```
#define VERTEXES 10

vector<int> adjacency_list[VERTEXES];

for ( int index = 0; index < VERTEXES; index++ ){
    cout << "List[" << index << "]: ";
    for (auto element : adjacency_list[index])
        cout << element << ", ";
    cout << ".\n";
}
```

Could the first `for` be replaced by a ranged `for` too, in order to *make the code simpler*? If so, how?

If it makes the code more complex I'm not interested, thank you. But, in this case, an explanation of *why* it cannot make the code simpler is welcome!

Comment: Well, may I ask why you're using a raw c-style array of vectors here? That's not very idiomatic c++ code. And yes, for that specific case you can use a range based for loop, since there's a definition for `std::begin(adjacency_list)` and `std::end(adjacency_list)`.

Comment: Making it "simpler" is entirely a matter of opinion. The direct answer to your question, however is yes, it can, ideally by const-reference. Frankly, I'm surprised you thought it easier to ask here rather than just *trying* it instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No specific reason. I took the program as a whole and was improving and adapting it to better adhere to C++, but got stuck on the nested ranged `for` before reaching the point of questioning myself about how the `vector`s were originally declared.

Comment: Did you actually mean to write `vector<int> adjacency_list(VERTEXES);` instead of creating an array of `vector<int>`s??

Comment: @WhozCraig I would try it if I knew what it is and how to try it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The person who wrote that line wasn't me. I just didn't touch it yet.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah well, then the information is finally not sufficient here. The code as is doesn't compile, and it's left completely unclear, what it is supposed to do. Can you [edit], and  fix that in your question please.

Comment: If you need to output the index, then a range-based loop (which hides that information away by default) is not the tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

> Could the first for be replaced by a ranged for too, in order to make the code simpler? If so, how?

Yes

```
for (auto& edge : adjacency_list){
    // cout << "List[" << index << "]: ";
    for (auto element : edge)
        cout << element << ", ";
    cout << ".\n";
}
```

Does it make the code *simpler*? That's up to you to decide, seeing as you are now missing the index of each edge. IMO, it is simpler/less code, therefore less thinking to comprehend.

Comment: ERROR on the first line when compiling: "error: no matching function for call to 'begin(std::vector<int>*&)'". The first line is "for (auto& edge : adjacency_list)".

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Sounds like your code doesn't look like what you've shown us. Are you e.g. passing `adjacency_list` as argument to function?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Correct!

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Well, then `adjacency_list` is not an array anymore. It [decayed to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/7976805) and lost all info about size. That means you can't use range-based loop on it. Index-based or iterator (pointer in this case) based loop is your only option.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Upgrading the array into a global variable would solve the problem without pointers. Wouldn't this be an option too?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Most people consider making a global variable a downgrade rather than upgrade. It is an option, but global variables have quite a lot of problems in long term.